# Is Sodium oleate vegetarian and/or vegan?

Tags: veganism, cosmetics

I am wondering if **Sodium Oleate** is vegetarian and/or vegan.

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleic_acid) article which might be about it, and I followed the links to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stearic_acid), which says that **Stearic acid** is obtained from **fats and oils by the saponification of the triglycerides using hot water**. So based on this might it be derived from animal sources? My chemistry knowledge is rather poor so I am kind of lost.

Also, according to [this](http://www.veganpeace.com/ingredients/ingredients.htm) website, **Oleic acid** can be derived from animal or non-animal sources. But is **Sodium oleate** the same as **Oleic acid**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sodium oleate is a salt of oleic acid (in chemistry terms, a salt is a substance formed when a metal (or other cation) replaces the hydrogen in an acid).

Therefore, you cannot know without further information whether sodium oleate is veg*n or not, since oleic acid may be derived from animal fats.

Check the labelling of the product to see whether it is suitable for veg*ns. Oleic acid is found in olive oil and the ingredients may say that the oleate was derived from olive oil, which would be a vegan source.